# Что делать с composer.json?

Tags: php, composer

Скачал с гитхаба библиотеку telegram-bot-sdk-master а там папка src и файл composer.json,  а мне нужно папку vendor и файл autoload.php, как с composer.json собрать библиотеку с папкой vendor?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если composer установлен глобально:

```
composer install
```

Если он у вас в виде phar файла, поместите его в папку с проектом и выполните:

```
php composer.phar install
```